# Is there a way to duplicate or make another copy of an XmlNodeList in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I load an XmlDocument and then select some nodes into an XmlNodeList instance. If I edit any of those nodes, the XmlDocument will be modified

```
XmlDocument xd = loadXml();
XmlNodeList xnl = xd.SelectNodes("/root/nodes");

foreach (XmlNode n in xnl)
{
    n.InnerText = "";
}
```

So I *understand* that modifying the XmlNodeList - modifies the XmlDocument that the node list was taken from.

Is there some way to create a deep copy (I think that's what I need) of the list of nodes into another XmlElement, so that when I modify these nodes they will be independent of the original location where they were copied from?

Comment: Take a look at the [`XmlNode`'s `clone()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clone.aspx). It does deep copies of a node. You already have the loop, so this should be not so difficult.

Comment: Aside from Clone(), Xml types are always easy to duplicate: write to and read from a (Memory)Stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one way to skin an xml cat. This is just one.

```
    var xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml("<root><nodes><node>1</node><node>2</node></nodes></root>");
    var xnl = xd.SelectSingleNode("/root/nodes").Clone();

    foreach (XmlNode n in xnl)
    {
        n.InnerText = "x";
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine(xd.OuterXml);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("--------------");
    Console.Out.WriteLine(xnl.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create your own copies using `.CloneNode`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clonenode.aspx) has an example.